# Javascript Slice Array Find Max

Tags: javascript

I want to slice an array and return one of the keys to push into another array. Pushing 1 item is simple.

```
array2.push(array1[index]['abc'])
```

I want to push the max value of a slice. This works:

```
array2.push(Math.max(array1[index1]['abc'], array1[index2]['abc'], array1[index3]['abc']))
```

Is there a cleaner way to format this with slicing?

Comment: do you only have 3 indexes in your array? If not, are `index1`, to `index3` continuous ints, or can they skip some (eg: index1 is `0` but index2 skips 1 as has the value of `2`)?

Comment: The length of the array is ~5000. Indexes are random numbers between 0 and 5000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an `indexes` array (of your random numbers) and then `.map()` that to their respective object `'abc'` values. Using the array of mapped values, you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it into `Math.max()` to find the max:

```js
const array1 = [{abc: 1}, {abc: 2}, {abc: -1}, {abc: 0}];
const indexes = [0, 2, 3]; // [index1, index2, index3] in your case

const max = Math.max(...indexes.map(i => array1[i]['abc']));
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the array and retrieve the object with property 'abc' (get's all continuous items in the array)

```
 array2.push(Math.max(...array1.map(x=>x['abc'])))
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I specify the index though? if I want index 0 through 3 or something. set x=3?

Comment: see the answer from @Nick Parsons

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions to this problem:

First, let's define our data.

```js
const firstArray = [{ abc : 1 }, { abc : 5 }, { abc : 3 }, { abc : 11 }, { abc : 2 }];
const secondArray = [];
```

1. Sort the first list and take the last item (not ideal)

```js
firstArray.sort((firstElem, secondElem) => firstElem.abc - secondElem.abc);
secondArray.push(firstArray[firstArray.length - 1].abc);

console.log(secondArray) // [ 11 ]
```

2. Use `Math.Max()` on the elements of `firstArray` (preferred):

```js
secondArray.push(Math.max(...firstArray.map(elem => elem.abc)));

console.log(secondArray); // [ 11 ]
```